# How to get total running balance with Vue js (Nested Array)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to get the running balance `Amort` - `AmountApplied`
This is the output I want to achieve

```
Line  Amort     Total Payment     Running Balance
 1    30250         10000             20250.00
      30250         20250             0.00
 2    30250         30250             0.00
```

In my vue

```
<table>
//...
<tbody v-for="(fetch,count,idx) in soaData">
<tr>
 // code
</tr>
<template v-for="(subFetch,count) in fetch.subPayments" >
<tr>
    <td class="text-right">{{subFetch.AmountApplied | formatNum}}</td>
    <td class="text-right">{{getRunningBal(fetch.subPayments,fetch.amortId)}}</td>
</tr>
</template>
</tbody>
</table>
```

in my methods

```
   getRunningBal(subPayments,amortId){

        let subpayCount = Object.values(this.soaData[amortId].subPayments).length
        let data = Object.values(this.soaData[amortId].subPayments)

        var total = 0;
        for(let i=0; i < subpayCount; i++){              
        return total += data[i].AmountApplied)
        }
```

my data

```
{
        "267": {
            "Ndays": 9,
            "DueDate": "2023-02-15",
            "Amort": 30250,
            "CheckNumber": "12341431",
            "DatePaid": "2022-10-07",
            "CheckStatus": "INVALID",
            "TotalRCF": null,
            "TotalDPF": null,
            "TotalHF": null,
            "amortCode": "11-9",
            "amortId": 267,
            "paymentAppliedID": 77,
            "DateDeposited": "2022-10-08",
            "ReDepositDate": null,
            "AmountApplied": 20250,
            "TotalPayables": 30250,
            "TotalPaymentsApplied": 30250,
            "subPayments": {
                "75": {
                    "AmountApplied": 10000,
                    "isCheck": 0,
                    "amortCode": "11-9",
                    "ReDepositDate": null,
                    "DateDeposited": null,
                    "DatePaid": "2022-10-07",
                    "CheckNumber": null,
                    "paymentAppliedID": 75,
                    "TotalPayables": 30250
                },
                "77": {
                    "AmountApplied": 20250,
                    "isCheck": 1,
                    "amortCode": "11-9",
                    "ReDepositDate": null,
                    "DateDeposited": "2022-10-08",
                    "DatePaid": "2022-10-07",
                    "CheckNumber": "12341431",
                    "paymentAppliedID": 77,
                    "TotalPayables": 30250
                }
            }
        },
        "270": {
            "Ndays": 12,
            "DueDate": "2023-03-30",
            "Amort": 30250,
            "CheckNumber": null,
            "DatePaid": "2022-10-07",
            "CheckStatus": "CASHREP",
            "TotalRCF": null,
            "TotalDPF": null,
            "TotalHF": null,
            "amortCode": "",
            "amortId": 270,
            "paymentAppliedID": 79,
            "DateDeposited": null,
            "ReDepositDate": null,
            "AmountApplied": 30250,
            "TotalPayables": 30250,
            "TotalPaymentsApplied": 30250,
            "subPayments": {
                "79": {
                    "AmountApplied": 30250,
                    "isCheck": 0,
                    "amortCode": "11-12",
                    "ReDepositDate": null,
                    "DateDeposited": null,
                    "DatePaid": "2022-10-07",
                    "CheckNumber": null,
                    "paymentAppliedID": 79,
                    "TotalPayables": 30250
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you have an unconditional `return` inside a for loop ... so it will never iterate more than once - plus you have a stray `)` that would mean your code wouldn't parse at all .... anyway ``for(let i=0; i < subpayCount; i++) { total += data[i].AmountApplied; } return total;``'

Comment: Thats why the total result is the same right? What Can I do?

Comment: @JaromandaX The out is still the same

Comment: well, let's look at the parameters for that function ... `subPayments` unused, `paymentAppliedID` unused, chances are, your logic is quite wrong

Comment: well, it's unclear what your code is trying to do - what is your intended purpose for those unused function arguments???

Comment: @JaromandaX I forgot to remove it sorry .. I already updated the question

Comment: Do you want runningBalance = Amort - sum(subPayments.AmountApplied) ?

Comment: @Zabon Yes bro I put in my question the sample of output that I want to do

Comment: Then your example is incorrect no ? Line1 (key 267) should be 30250 - (10000 + 20250) = 0

Comment: Thats correct .. the output is like that because the `subPayments` in nested array is having a 2 object

Comment: @Zabon I'm getting the running balance its not going to sum all at once .. the payment must be distributed each line

Answer (score 0):

Since may nested array index is using ID as index so I make it like this v-`for="(subFetch,key,count) in fetch.subPayments"` to get the index starting with 0

```
<table>
//...
<tbody v-for="(fetch,count,idx) in soaData">
<tr>
 // code
</tr>
<template v-for="(subFetch,key,count) in fetch.subPayments" >
<tr>
    <td class="text-right">{{subFetch.AmountApplied | formatNum}}</td>
    <td class="text-right">{{getRunningBal(fetch.subPayments,fetch.amortId)}}</td>
</tr>
</template>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I get the index of subPayments to get the sum of each line and it works

```
    getRunningBal(subPayments,amortId, count){    
    let subpayCount = Object.values(this.soaData[amortId].subPayments).length
    let data = Object.values(this.soaData[amortId].subPayments)

    var total = 0;
    for(let i=0; i <= count; i++){              
     total += data[i].AmountApplied
    }
        return total       
    },
```